# jQuery ajax load() java script not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I've read several posts about this issue but i can't solve it.

I am loading an html file into a div. The file i am loading contains a unordered list.
This list should be expanded (a menu with submenu items) and closed. Therefore i need js.
But unfortunately this script isn't loaded.

Can anyone help me?

Would be so great! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Show us some code...

Comment: Better answer from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16352425/484358

Answer (score 12):

You want to load via AJAX into a div on your page, lets call it;

1) `<div id="loadStuffHere"></div>` of (abc.html)

2) the stuff to populate `loadStuffHere` comes from xyz.html

So just do this;

```
$("loadStuffHere").load("xyz.html");
```

BUT WAIT!! You dont want to have to load everything from xyz.html you just want to load a portion of xyz.html say `<div id="loadMeOnly"></div>` of (xyz.html)

So just do this;

```
$("loadStuffHere").load("xyz.html #loadMeOnly");
```

BUT WAIT!! Lets say inside of `<div id="loadMeOnly"></div>` is an accordion so which means it has to be initialized which means u have to also include the javascripts... hmm, what to do...

You would think of doing this;

```
$("loadStuffHere").load("xyz.html #loadMeOnly");
$.getScript('js/xyz.js');
```

Well the above sucks because a) u would need to create an external js file and b) You are actually making 2 http calls, when u could do it with 1 http call if you did it by normal non-ajax way.

The best solution is to get 2 things with 1 call the (HTML and the js - 1 line, 1 http) here is how u do it;

```
$("loadStuffHere").load("xyz.html #loadMeOnly, script");
```

This loads the `#loadMeOnly` div AND all `script` tags

The trick here is commas. You could pick and choose to load whatever doms you want

Comment: Except -- now that you have loaded that script, how to you run it?

Answer (score 2):

So lets make sure you have jQuery loaded in the first place, be sure that the link to the library is in the head of your HTML, so something like this:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to make sure it is loaded by checking the "net" tab.

Also be sure you are loading *your* javascript: (here I've called it "main")

```
<script src="/javascripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then in your js file do something like:

```
$.(document).load( function () {
  alert("loaded!")
});
```

That should fire the alert once the page has "fully loaded" I prefer to use `ready()` which will fire once the DOM is loaded.

If you have this all working and what you actually want to do is load and execute js from your js file try this:

```
.getScript()
```

This will load and execute the JavaScript you want.

Comment: Thanks!
Where and how do i have to use this?
is there no other possibility?

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble figuring out what you want to do, do you know for sure if jQuery is loaded on your page in the first place?

Comment: yes, my page works so far. jquery has to work to because of the lod() request. The only thing is the js in loaded content. I don't know how to solve that... :(

Comment: okay thanks jpsilvashy i'll test it and well be back in a minute :)

Answer (score 2):

Juhu. I've solved it. Don't know wheather this is the most elegant way but it works :)

jpsilvashy your getscript(); has done it :) I've included these two lines in my content which should be loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.getScript("js/tutorial-1.js");
$.getScript("js/jquery.ahover.js");
</script>
```

that works.

For everyone who has the same problem there's a small hint. You should delete the body and head tags. If they are included it doesn't work.

But now there's still a question: Why do i need to include this in the loaded content?
I think the JavaScript has to be loaded after the content was loaded into the dom.

But that only some assumption!

Thanks for your great help!

Comment: does no one knows an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

This solution works best. Using a callback function after the specific div or content container is loaded.

```
$('#CONTAINER').load('URL_TO_LOAD HTML_ELEMENT_TO_PLUCK_FROM_PAGE_AND_INSERT_INTO_CONTAINER', function () {
    $.getScript('PATH_TO_SCRIPT_THAT_YOU_REQUIRE_FOR_LOADED_CONTENT');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The script can't use document.ready, the document already ready. Just put the script between script tags.

wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       alert($('div').html());
   });
</script>
```

correct:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       alert($('div').html());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I see... If you just want to load some html use:

```
$("selector for div ").load("/path_to_html.html div#main");
```

Where `div#main` is the `div` I want to retrieve in your remote file, but remember this must be the same domain for it to work.

Comment: that works, the menu you see is the loaded content. this menu should be folded together(the js makes that). and this script is not loaded.
thats the problem :)

Comment: just to make it clear how it should look like.
open http://johnlikesit.jo.ohost.de/helpme/htmlcontent.html
i've included the js files in the second file to show you what i mean :)

Comment: even when the js files are included in both(the first file and the html file that should be loaded in the first one it doesn't work :(

Comment: so you shouldn't need any javascript in the file that is being loaded, we are only modifying the DOM so what is being inserted will still be under the influence of the js you have running under your original file, including all you events and everything. I'm not sure what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, is there anyway you can try to explain it a different way?

Comment: okay, i'll try to :)
the part which should be inserted contains a menu which can be expanded. Without javascript this couldn't be done(as far as i know).

So first i load the html content from the file "htmlcontent.html" into the div "container" in my "index_helpme.html"

This works so far. The only problem is interacting with the loaded htmlcontent.html. If i want to change the css style with jquery or make some effects, it doesn't work.

I hope this explanation is clear to understand :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: probably there's a better way to build up a homepage instead of loading the content through jquery. i don't know. if you have some tips, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can load javascript file dynamically with help of `jQuery.getScript` and set a callback function. When the script has been loaded the callback function called. Here's an example of loading *highlightjs* library from *cdnjs*:

```
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.6/highlight.min.js", function () {
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        // hljs now is available
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly call ahover on the unordered list. See the [documentaton](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ahover/wiki/Documentation).