# auto refresh a div not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to develop a div that is automatically updated with your own content as it will be to show a real ping a website on canvas.
I have the following script:

```
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#divcanvas').fadeOut('slow').load('teste.php #divcanvas').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
</script>
```

In my markup have:

```
<div style="width:30%">
    <div id="divcanvas">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in test.php have:

```
<?php 
include_once "ping/pingdomain.php";
require_once "ping/config.php";
$ms = pingDomain('www.adhenrique.com.br');
$hora = date("H:i:s", time());
mysql_query("insert into ping (resposta, horario) values ('$ms', '$hora')");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PING order by id DESC LIMIT 0,15");
?>
<head>
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="includes/js/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
<?php
$pingreposta = array();
$pinghorario = array();
while($valor = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    extract($valor);
    $pinghorario[] = $valor['horario'];
    $pingreposta[] = $valor['resposta'];
}
?>
    <script>
        var lineChartData = {
            labels :<?php echo '[' .'"'. implode('","', $pinghorario) .'"'. ']'; ?>
            ,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : <?php echo '[' . implode(',', $pingreposta) . ']'; ?>

                }
            ]

        }

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }


    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when i open the index.php, it does not show the canvas. But if i open the test.php data it shows. That is, the code of canvas is correct.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is `teste.php` & `#divcanvas` in `load('teste.php #divcanvas')` a copy/paste error? Should it be `.load('test.php').`

Comment: @Sean i had tested the same way, and so does not work. :(

Comment: possible issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/16352425/689579?

Answer (score 1):

At this line, you did a typo:

```
$('#divcanvas').fadeOut('slow').load('teste.php #divcanvas').fadeIn("slow");
```

**teste.php** should be **test.php** I guess.

Comment: Yes. :D Sorry. It was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `load('teste.php #divcanvas')` in that way you're requesting only #divcanvas from teste.php (which not exists) according to [jQuery.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

I would prefer this kind of approach using ajax

### main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="chart.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divcanvas').fadeOut('slow');

    // Set "active" to true to animate addData()
    var chartAnimation = {"active":false,"time":250,"currentTime":0,"currentIndex":0};
    var data = new Array();
    var label = new Array();

    var lineChartData = {
        labels: [],
        datasets : [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: []
        }]
    };

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });

    $.get("test.php", function(res) {
        res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
        $('#divcanvas').fadeIn("slow")
        for (var key in res) {
            var arr = new Array(res[key])
            data.push(arr);
            label.push(key);
            if (chartAnimation.active) {
                chartAnimation.currentTime += chartAnimation.time;
                setTimeout(function(){myLine.addData(data[chartAnimation.currentIndex],label[chartAnimation.currentIndex]); chartAnimation.currentIndex++;},chartAnimation.currentTime);
            } else {
                myLine.addData(arr,key);
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
<div style="width:30%">
    <div id="divcanvas">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

### test.php

```
<?php 
include_once "ping/pingdomain.php";
require_once "ping/config.php";
$ms = pingDomain('www.adhenrique.com.br');
$hora = date("H:i:s", time());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ping (resposta, horario) VALUES (".$ms.", ".$hora.")");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PING order by id DESC LIMIT 0,15");
$resp = array();
while ($valor = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $resp[$valor['horario']] = $valor['resposta'];
}
echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

Chart animation added just for fun :)

Comment: Got it perfectly. I did as you said but nothing appears. :(

Comment: I added an example using ajax