# Loading external html files to div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to load an external html file into the div element.
My jquery code is:

```
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
       $('#profile').on('click',function()
       {
           $.get('hn.html')
               .success(function(data) {
                   $('#a').html(data);
               });

       });
    });
    <a  id="profile" href="#profile" >
```

my hn.html file is :

```
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="bootstrap/js/tab.js"></script>
       <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#branch').append('<option>Select Branch</option>');
     $('#branch').append('<option>ComputerScience</option>');
     $('#branch').append('<option>Electrical</option>');
     $('#branch').append('<option>Electronics and Communication</option>');
     $('#branch').append('<option>Mechanical</option>');
     $('#tier').append('<option>Select tier</option>');
     $('#tier').append('<option>I</option>');
     $('#tier').append('<option>II</option>');
     $('#tier').append('<option>III</option>');
     $('#type').append('<option>Type of Internship/Placement</option>');
     $('#type').append('<option>6 weeks</option>');
     $('#type').append('<option>6 months</option>');
     $('#type').append('<option>Full Time</option>');


     $('#branch').on('change', function () {
         var m = $("#branch option:selected").text();

         if (m == 'ComputerScience') {
             $('#skill1').append('<option>Select Skill 1</option>');
             $('#skill1').append('<option>Algorithms</option>');
             $('#skill1').append('<option>Data Structures</option>');
             $('#skill1').append('<option>Web Development</option>');
             $('#skill1').append('<option>Computer Networking</option>');
             $('#skill1').append('<option>Database Management</option>');
             $('#skill2').append('<option>Select Skill 2</option>');
             $('#skill2').append('<option>Algorithms</option>');
             $('#skill2').append('<option>Data Structures</option>');
             $('#skill2').append('<option>Web Development</option>');
             $('#skill2').append('<option>Computer Networking</option>');
             $('#skill2').append('<option>Database Management</option>');
             $('#skill3').append('<option>Select Skill 3</option>');
             $('#skill3').append('<option>Algorithms</option>');
             $('#skill3').append('<option>Data Structures</option>');
             $('#skill3').append('<option>Web Development</option>');
             $('#skill3').append('<option>Computer Networking</option>');
             $('#skill3').append('<option>Database Management</option>');

         }
     });
     $('#skill1').on('change', function ()
     {
         var n = $("#skill1 option:selected").text();
         var index = $('#skill1').get(0).selectedIndex;
         $('#skill2 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
         $('#skill3 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();






     });
     $('#skill2').on('change', function ()
     {
         var p = $("#skill2 option:selected").text();
         var index1 = $('#skill2').get(0).selectedIndex;

         $('#skill3 option:eq(' + index1 + ')').remove();






     });
     $('#skill3').on('change', function ()
     {
         var r = $("#skill3 option:selected").text();
         var index2 = $('#skill3').get(0).selectedIndex;











     });

    $('#save1').on('click',function()
    {
       $.post('n.php',{'name': $('name').val(),'rollno': $('rollno').val(), 'mobile': $('mobile').val(), 'fblink': $('fblink').val(), 'linkedin': $('linkedin').val(),'skypelink': $('skypelink').val()},function(data) {
           if(data=='success') {
               $('#myModal').modal('show');

           }
       });

    });
     $('#save2').on('click',function()
     {
         $.post('c.php',{'10percentage': $('10percentage').val(),'12percentage': $('12percentage').val(), 'cgpa': $('cgpa').val(), 'sgpa1': $('sgpa1').val(), 'sgpa2': $('sgpa2').val(),'sgpa3': $('sgpa3').val(), 'sgpa4': $('sgpa4').val(),'sgpa5': $('sgpa5').val()},function(data) {
             if(data=='success') {
                 $('#myModal1').modal('show');

             }
         });

     });

     $('#save3').on('click',function()
     {
         $.post('d.php',{'branch': $('branch').val(),'skill1': $('skill1').val(), 'skill2': $('skill2').val(), 'skill3': $('skill3').val(), 'tier': $('tier').val(),'type': $('type').val()},function(data) {
             if(data=='success') {
                 $('#myModal2').modal('show');

             }
         });

     });
 });

</script>



         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="span12">
        <div class="" id="loginModal">
          <div class="modal-header">

            <h3>Create User Profile</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="well">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Personal Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Educational Details</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#skill" data-toggle="tab">Skills </a> </li>
              </ul>
              <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" action='n.php' method="POST">
                    <br>
                    <fieldset>
                      <div id="legend">
                        <legend class="">Personal Details</legend>
                      </div>    
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="name">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password-->
                        <label class="control-label" for="rollno">Roll No</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="rollno" name="rollno" placeholder="Enter Roll No" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password-->
                        <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Mobile No</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile No" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password-->
                        <label class="control-label" for="fblink">Facebook link</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="fblink" name="fblink" placeholder="Enter Facebook Profile Link" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password-->
                        <label class="control-label" for="linkedin">LinkedIn link</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="linkedin" name="linkedin" placeholder="Enter LinkedIn Profile Link" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Password-->
                        <label class="control-label" for="skypelink">Skype Link</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="skypelink" name="skypelink" placeholder="Enter Skype Profile Link" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <br>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="controls">
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="save1" id="save1">Save</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>                
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
                  <form id="tab">
                    <br>
                    <fieldset>
                      <div id="legend">
                        <legend class="">Educational Details</legend>
                      </div>  
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="10percentage">Class 10 percentage</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="10percentage" name="10percentage" placeholder="Enter class 10 percentage" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="12percentage">Class 12 percentage</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="12percentage" name="12percentage" placeholder="Enter class 12 percentage" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="cgpa"> Overall CGPA</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="cgpa" name="cgpa" placeholder="Enter CGPA" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="sgpa1">SGPA for Semester 1</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="sgpa1" name="sgpa1" placeholder="Enter SGPA for Semester 1" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="sgpa2">SGPA for Semester 2</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="sgpa2" name="sgpa2" placeholder="Enter SGPA for Semester 2" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="sgpa3">SGPA for Semester 3</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="sgpa3" name="sgpa3" placeholder="Enter SGPA for Semester 3" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="sgpa4">SGPA for Semester 4</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="sgpa4" name="sgpa4" placeholder="Enter SGPA for Semester 4" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="sgpa5">SGPA for Semester 5</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="sgpa5" name="sgpa5" placeholder="Enter SGPA for Semester 5" class="input-xlarge">
                        </div>
                      </div>







                       <br>
                   <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="controls">
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="save2" id="save2">Save</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                </div> 
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="skill">
                  <form id="tab">
                    <br>
                    <fieldset>
                      <div id="legend">
                        <legend class="">Skills</legend>
                      </div>  
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label"  for="branch">Branch</label>
                        <div class="controls">
            <select name="branch"  class="form-control input-sm" id="branch" name="branch"  placeholder="Enter branch">
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="skill1">Skill 1</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <select name="skill1"  class="form-control input-sm" id="skill1" name="skill1" placeholder="Enter skill 1">
              </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="skill2"> Skill 2</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="skill2"  class="form-control input-sm" id="skill2" name="skill2" placeholder="Enter skill 2">
              </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="skill3">Skill 3</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="skill3"  class="form-control input-sm" id="skill3" name="skill3" placeholder="Enter skill 3">
              </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="tier">Preferred company tier</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="tier"  class="form-control input-sm" id="tier" name="tier"  placeholder="tier">
              </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="type">Type of placement required</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="type"  class="form-control input-sm" id="type" name="type"  placeholder="Enter type of placement">
              </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>






                    <br> 
                   <div class="control-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="controls">
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-left" name="save3" id="save3">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                </div> 


            </div>   
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

     <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Success</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                 <p>Your Educational details have been successfully saved</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Success</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You have successfully created your profile</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But it is not appending any data to my id of div when i am using get to extract. Please help me rectify my mistake.

Comment: Please also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352371/jquery-load-ajax-not-executing-javascript-in-returned-html-after-appende

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancel the link too

```
$(function() {
  $('#profile').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#a').load("hn.html");
  });
});
```

Please note that you may want to change your hn.html because of the script in it

[jQuery .load() / .ajax() not executing javascript in returned HTML after appended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352371/jquery-load-ajax-not-executing-javascript-in-returned-html-after-appende)

[**Here is a live example**](http://plungjan.name/SO/demo.html) using your file and this markup for the first page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $('#profile').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#a').load("hn.html");
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a id="profile" href="#profile">Click</a>
 <div id="a"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To get your script to execute you can move the script from hn.html to and external file and do

```
$('#a').load("hn.html",function(){
  $.getScript("externalhnscript.js");
});
```

Comment: the method is not working for me nothing is getting loaded into the div content

Comment: yes it is showing Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/placement/js/bootstrap.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/placement/css/queryLoader.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/placement/css/bootstrap.css.map:1 GET http://localhost/placement/css/bootstrap.css.map 404 (Not Found)
slick.css.map:1 GET http://localhost/placement/css/slick.css.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That should not mean anything. However the html is not valid. I am trying to load your file on my server give me a minute

Comment: Please see update. I think perhaps you have issues with the code. For example you have many duplicate IDs so perhaps the #a you want to load into is not what I thought you meant. See my demo

Comment: I did the load method it is working properly but i am not able to extract the script part out of my hn.html

Comment: So extract it to external JS and use getScript in the success function - see update

Comment: My page now loads some skills. See the content of hn1.html too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76800/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-ten-do). "It is not working" is not a useful comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can load the external file directly by load()

```
$('#profile').on('click',function(){
       $(this).load('hn.html');
});
```