# call jquery function from other page

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem i'm loading page in my div using ajax 
here is a code

Html

```
<div id="body"></div>
<a class='olink' href='#'>page name</a>
```

script

```
$('.olink').on('click',function(e){ 
    var link = this.href;
    $.ajax({ 
        url: page, 
        type:'POST', 
        data : name, 
        success: function(resp){ 
            $("#body").html(resp); 
        } 
        e.preventDefault();  
    }); 
});
```

The above code working fine and load page in my div, now problem is when i click on any link from loaded page this script not working... currently i add my script in the bottom of main page,, should i add this script on every page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .load() / .ajax() not executing javascript in returned HTML after appended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352371/jquery-load-ajax-not-executing-javascript-in-returned-html-after-appende)

Comment: Add any common scripts like that to a separate JavaScript file and include that with every page. That's far better than copy/pasting the same code onto multiple pages.

Comment: Scripts don't execute when setting them with `$.html()` (or with innerHTML for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

> **Script Execution**
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into `#a` as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> ```
> $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
> ```
>
> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being
>   loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> ```
> $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
> ```

you can also
you can use `$.getScript("url");` to get script or `eval` youe source like `eval(source)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you are trying to get your script to fire when clicking on a link from within the #body element then you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$('#body').on('click', '.olink', function() {
  var link = this.href;
    $.ajax({ 
        url: page, 
        type:'POST', 
        data : name, 
        success: function(resp){ 
            $("#body").html(resp); 
        } 
        e.preventDefault();  
    }); 
});
```