# Differences in jQuery.load(url) with a full document and partial document with scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does `jQuery.load(url)` prevent scripts within the url content to run when the content is a fragment of a page?

For example, when the content is returned in the manner below, the embedded scripts are executed.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        </script>  
        <table>
        </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, when the content is returned in the following format, the scripts do not run.(note: there are no external references in the scripts)

```
<script>
</script>  
<table>
</table>
```

I am using

```
$('#myDiv').load(contentUrl);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked [this answer already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317080/jquery-ajax-load-java-script-not-executing)? Maybe that helps :)

Comment: Scripts are executed in the browser, and pages loaded through AJAX calls are fetched directly from the web server as plain text. I would strongly discourage the approach of running scripts loaded from another page. If the scripts are yours, include them on your pages and trigger functionality when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you TRUST, the source of the load, then you could do this:

```
$('#myDiv').load(contentUrl, function(){
   $(this).find('script').each(function(){
     eval(this);
   });
});
```

Please note I said TRUST.

Comment: Yes, i get what you are saying about trust. And thanks, after two days of spinning my wheels your answer worked for me. However, it just proved what I thought might be the case. The script in the content is slowing rendering when placed in the dom. I was trying to get away from using an iframe where the content images were resized and the content rendered in 2 seconds. Using div.load() and div.html() takes 15 seconds with the same content when the scripts are evaluated :(