# JQuery .Load() javascript not executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

I'm having major problems. I have a page called dashboard.php but the actual page div (ID = #dashboardcontainer) is empty as I am filling the content with this script:

```
$('#dashboardcontainer').load('functions/pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php');
```

then I tried:

```
$.getScript("assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.2/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", function(){
$('#dashboardcontainer').load('functions/pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php');
})
```

However, the page I am wanting to "inject" actually has Javascript in it. The problem is, the above javascript's .load() doesn't load the javascript in the file.

I've tried lots of other examples from the following posts but they don't work at all. The javascript isn't actually loading.

[jQuery .load() / .ajax() not executing javascript in returned HTML after appended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352371/jquery-load-ajax-not-executing-javascript-in-returned-html-after-appende)

```
$.get('partial.html', function(result){
$result = $(result);

$result.find('#content').appendTo('#new_content');
$result.find('script').appendTo('#new_content');
}, 'html');
```

= No javascript firing.

[jQuery ajax load() java script not executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317080/jquery-ajax-load-java-script-not-executing)

```
$("loadStuffHere").load("xyz.html"); $.getScript('js/xyz.js');
```

= Still no javascript firing.

I can't use lots of PHP includes as I receive conflicts which stops my page from rendering correctly.

I've also tried using some sort of Json thing to hide and show dom elements but I hate how complex it is to modify and insert new data.

Is there any simple (this term doesn't seem to exist in the web development dictionary) way I can actually inject a web page that contains it's own javascript in the same way a PHP include would render it?

Here is the PHP page I am trying to inject:

```
<?php
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This is the sub-page");</script>';
?>
```

Comment: A Fiddle might help you get a few more responses

Comment: I would love to create one but I am still learning all of this kind of stuff. I'd struggle even building a Fiddle that demonstrated my error as my website is a purchased theme from wrap bootstrap (if i am even allowed to mention the site?)

Comment: Is this javascript the only thing you're trying to run? Or do you want to include html too?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.get("functions/pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php"
  , function(script, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(typeof script, textStatus
                , jqxhr.responseText
                , jqxhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
    $("head").prepend(script);
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(jqxhr.responseText, errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! So the page contents is inserted but the actual javascript elements still don't function. 

I did have to change the $("head") to $("#dashboardcontainer") so it injected the code into the correct area.

I left the javascript links in on the parent dashboard.php page, no luck. I moved all the javascripts into the sub-page dashboard_admin.php, still no luck.

Comment: If possible, can post return values of `console.log()` ? Does `jqxhr.responseText` return `<script type="text/javascript">alert("This is the sub-page");</script> success ` ?

Comment: This is what console.log says: [Log] string success <script type="text/javascript>alert("this is the sub-page");</script>" text/html (dashboard.php, line 320)....... But the actual alert() doesn't load when the page opens

Comment: Update: I just made a fresh dashboard_customer.php file which echoes the alert() and <p>testing</p>. This now works. Unusual as the files were identical... However, now I try insert the desired content (panels, graphs and lists) the required javascript references do not work. If I put the required code into dashboard.php the page looks and works great.